# How to get a build number in Java for Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am building an application in Java for Google App Engine. I would like to display some kind of build number within my application. It could be the compile date and time, unless there is some really easy way to implement some kind of auto-incrementing integer.

Assuming the compile date and time is the easiest approach, is there a macro or some other way to get this compile-time information at runtime? Maybe something like the C++ `__DATE__` macro? Or by interrogating the Application object itself?

FWIW, I am not after the version number stored in the appengine-web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism we supply is version number. One of the big benefits of version numbers is that it lets you upload an app with new index definitions, wait for the new indexes to be built, and *then* switch the new version to be the default.

If you want some sort of date or version stamp embedded in the app itself, you'll need to do that as part of your build pipeline. E.g., wrap `appcfg.sh` in a shell script that updates a stamp in a file first.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [Maven Build Number Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/). This requires that you use Maven as build tool. Luckily, these days Google provides the [official Maven Appengine Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/). As an alternative to the Build Number Plugin, you could use the [build timestamp](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Special_Variables) and [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).